# Gradle Sync Failed after migrating from kapt to KSP

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying migrating from kapt to KSP following the [official guide](https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-ksp).

I am getting the following error when syncing the project.

> Unable to find method
> ''org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinAndroidTarget
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinJvmAndroidCompilation.getTarget()''
> 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinAndroidTarget
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinJvmAndroidCompilation.getTarget()'
>
> Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after
> a network connection timeout.)
>
> Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network) The state
> of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle
> daemons may solve this problem.
>
> Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart) Your project may be
> using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other
> plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the
> project.
>
> In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the
> IDE and then killing all Java processes.

I have tried the suggested solutions, none of this works. Here is my `app/build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "kotlin-parcelize"
    id "com.google.devtools.ksp" version "1.8.21-1.0.11"
    id "com.google.gms.google-services"
    id "com.google.firebase.crashlytics"
    id "com.google.firebase.appdistribution"
    id "com.google.firebase.firebase-perf"
}

...

dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.5.1"
    ksp "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.1"

    implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.15.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-adapters:1.14.0"
    ksp "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.14.0"
...
```

I am **NOT** using `kapt` or `ksp` anywhere else, I even tried replacing `ksp` with `kapt` in the dependencies, and just import `ksp`, and still getting the same error.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out that I should have added the following block of code in the **Project's** `build.gradle`.

```
plugins {
    id "com.google.devtools.ksp" version "1.8.21-1.0.11" apply false
}
```

And replacing in **Module's** `build.gradle`

```
id "com.google.devtools.ksp" version "1.8.21-1.0.11"
```

to

```
id "com.google.devtools.ksp"
```

Comment: Saved my lots of hours.

Comment: Your ksp version helped me to solve my sync problem. You saved my day.